# Is elastic search overkill for what I am trying to achieve?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very popular conference directory listings resource.

I'd like to create a way to make the listing searchable - and my understanding that elastic search offers a ton of usability and features - especially with regards to metrics.

Here's my question: is Elastic search ONLY for huge (large) datasets?

My data is not big at all (it all loads in a simple static HTML file...)

Comment: Probably overkill, but what features do you need?

Comment: @Ryan thanks for reply - the only features I really need is javascript filtering - and some outbound link (click) analytics...

Comment: What’s “filtering”, though? Exact word matches? Fuzzy? Google levels of searching by word meaning?

Comment: By filtering what I mean is keywords that are embedded within simple html <div> keyword </div> - I am thinking that jQuery would work well for this?

Comment: `elastic`search.  It scales to any use case.  Most use cases you hear about online are for huge datasets, because that is the primary problem Elasticsearch solves, however it is applicable to any case.  Provided you can meet the minimum hardware spec of Elasticsearch (most cloud environments start at 1GB RAM), you can use it for whatever you want.

Comment: If its just a few keywords you might also have a look at angular